# How to squash Dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Assume I have a hierarchy of images, one inheriting from the other with FROM:

- B: FROM A
- C: FROM B
- D: FROM C

A is a standard base image, and B,C,D are my own images.

Now I need to create a Dockerfile for D', with same additions coming from Dockerfiles of B, C and D, but based on a different base image - A'.

I can think of a couple of ways to achieve this:

1. Create dockerfile for B', identical to B but inheriting from A'. Same for C' and D'.
2. Create a completely new Dockerfile for D', with base image A' and copy-pasting all the commands from dockerfiles of B, C and D.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I guess a tool/scrtipt that would do #2 might be enough.

Comment: Everything you said is correct. I think you already know the answer. There are some tools you can search for to "squash" B, C, and D into a single Dockerfile if you want.

Comment: @mkasberg I didn't find such a tool. Can you point to one?